# Modifying an immutable object in a factory function

Tags: python, design-patterns, constructor, immutability, software-design

Is there a design pattern that describes the following setup? Does this design suffer from any major issues?

Class `Widget` instances can be built either by a "dumb" constructor `Widget.__init__()`, or by an "intelligent" factory method `Workbench.upgrade_widget()`:

```
class Widget:
  def __init__(self, abc, def, ...):
    self.abc = abc
    self.def = def
    ...
  ...

class Workbench:

  # widget factory function, which uses data from the workbench instance
  def upgrade_widget(self, widget, upgrade_info):
    widget = Widget(widget.abc, widget.def, ...)
    # I will modify the widget's attributes
    ...
    self.rearrange_widget(widget, xyz) # modifies widget's internal state
    ...
    widget.abc = ... # also modifies widget's state
    ...
    return widget

  # uses data from the workbench instance
  def rearrange_widget(self, widget, xyz):
    ...
  # this class does other stuff too
  ...
```

Widgets are immutable in the sense that I must not modify its instances after they are fully initialized (a lot of code depends on this invariant). But I find that modifying widgets *while* they are being initialized is very convenient, and makes the code much cleaner.

My main concern is that I modify "immutable" widgets in a different class. If it was only in `upgrade_widget`, I might live with it since it does not modify the widget passed to it. But that method relies on other `Workbench` methods (`rearrange_widget`) which modifies the widget it received as an argument. I feel like I'm losing control over where this "immutable" instance can actually be modified - someone may accidentally call `rearrange_widget` with a widget that's already fully initialized, leading to a disaster.

Comment: Aside from the question: in Python 2, always inherit your classes from "object" - else you may suffer from lack of features and hard to diagnose misbehavior, as classes not inheriting from object are old style classes.

Comment: Sorry should have said it's Python 3....

Answer (score 1):

How are you enforcing immutability of the Widget now?

What if you add a 'locked' property to your widget, and wrap your setattr to check that property:

```
class Widget(object):
    __locked = False
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,locked=True):
        ...
        self.__locked = locked

    def lock(self):
        self.__locked = True

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.__locked

    def __setattr___(self,*args,**kw):
        if self.__locked:
            raise Exception('immutable') # define your own rather than use Exception
        return super(Widget).__setattr__(self,*args,**kw)
```

then in the factory:

```
class Workbench(object):
    def upgrade_widget(self,widget,upgrade_info):
        widget = Widget(widget.a,widget.b,...,locked=False)
        self.rearrange_widget(widget, blah)
        widget.c = 1337
        widget.lock()
        return widget
```

In general use you can be pretty certain that nothing funny happens to the class once it's locked. Any methods which care about the immutability of the widget should also check the is_locked() of that widget. For example, rearrange_widget should check that the widget is unlocked too before doing anything.

This is notwithstanding malicious tampering with the instances, which can happen anyway. it also doesn't prevent attributes being changed by their own methods.

Note that the code (pseudo python) I wrote above isn't tested, but hopefully it illustrates the general idea of how to deal with your main concern.

Oh, and I'm not sure if there's a particular name for this pattern.

Comment: btw, whenever i've done this, i usually implement the locking in it's own class and inherit from it... something like class Lockable(object): ... class Widget(Lockable): ...

Answer (score 1):

@chees:  A neater way of doing that is to modify `__dict__` in `__init__` and make `__setattr__` always raise an exception (btw, its not a good idea to `raise Exception` - its just to general):

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.__dict__['args'] = args

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise TypeError
```

And modifying it in the same way in Workbench (i.e. using `__dict__`) is a constant reminder that you're doing something you shouldn't really be doing.

Comment: agree with not raising Exception - wrote that just for convenience as you could implement your own exceptions are required (i'll put a comment to that effect). i do find that accessing attributes via the dict is a bit of a drag if you have to do a lot of it, though that does make it a good disincentive...

Comment: Exactly.  Sometimes you want the API to be a drag as a reminder that you shouldn't really be doing it - rather like accessing a double-underscored private attribute from outside a class.